# How to make SharePoint display computer status and calendar?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I want to add to my SharePoint site something like a Web Part that will ping a computer 
and say if this computer is online - how can I do this?

Another question is how can I connect two SharePoint calendars: if someone update one of them the other will update too?

Thanks.

Comment: The is two separate questions - so you should put it in as two separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, you can create a workflow in sharepoint designer to add a new calendar item in the second calendar every time the first calendar has a new item.